# Center ajax loader

Tags: css

I am trying to center the ajax loader. But no luck. Loader appears on right corner of the screen. Appreciate assistance. Below is the code

```
div.amshopby-overlay {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 555;
}
div.amshopby-overlay img {
    top: 100px;
    left: 45%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

div.amshopby-overlay div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background:  url('../images/amshopby-overlay.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: can you add more of your `html` code please or add a working jsfiddle demo to get more idea of this. Thank you

Comment: I copied this from a css file. The extension has few phtml and js file. Not sure which one to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="loader.gif" class="loader">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
 .container{position:relative; height:300px;width:300px;}
 .loader{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution I like to do when whatever I'm centering is just an image is to do it with the css background property:

## HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

## CSS

```
#container.loader{
    background:url('loader.gif') center center no-repeat;
}
```

Now in your javascript, add the class `loader` when you make the ajax request and remove the class on complete.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume the div inside the amshopby-overlay contains your loader image. Give it a try:

```
div.amshopby-overlay div {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background:  url('../images/amshopby-overlay.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  /* Add this */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
```

Basically, top and left will push the div 50% from top and left. And we will add -50% of the div width and height value to center in vertically and horizontally. Give it a try. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

"margin: auto" should give you the centering style you want.  CSS details below.

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="loader">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
     /*Absolute positioning will now be relative to this tag*/
     position:relative; 

     /*Arbitrary Height*/
     height:300px;
     width:300px;

     /*border to show container*/
     border: 1px solid;
 }

.loader {
    /*Allow top, left, right, bottom 
    to be set relative to container*/
    position: absolute;

    /*Set edges of tag so margin auto knows the max boundry*/
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

    /*Allows the use of margin auto*/
    display: block;

    /*Horizontally and vertically centered
    (Display block will fill remaining margin space equally)*/
    margin: auto;
}
```

### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/16vrxgxh/1/